# Is there a URL Rewrite module for Sitecore 10.1.0?

Tags: url-rewrite

Does anyone know of a URL Rewrite module that is compatible with Sitecore 10.1.0 without SXA?

Answer (score 2):

Installing `Constellation.Feature.Redirects` gets you a new Sitecore `app` for the Sitecore Desktop called `Redirect Manager`. This application allows you to create, update, export, and import a list of marketing redirects.

You also get an Item Template that you can use to insert a `Page Redirect` anywhere in your content tree. This allows you to create `short` URLs that link to deeper content, or to host a URL within a given section of your site that points to something external to that branch of the content tree.

**Installation**
`Constellation.Feature.Redirects` is managed via NuGet.

In Visual Studio, fire up the Package Manager console and install into a Web Application project:

> PM:> Install-Package Constellation.Feature.Redirects

Once you will install this library you will get the option `Redirect Manager` in Desktop from Launchpad.
[image]

Click on the redirect manager and it will redirect you to the new Window:

[image]

In the Redirect Windows manager, you can perform the below operation

1. Adding a New Marketing Redirect
2. Editing Existing Redirects
3. Importing and Exporting Marketing Redirects

See the blog post for more details: [Redirects](https://constellation4sitecore.com/feature/redirects/)

**Compatibility**: Yes, It's compatible with `Sitecore 10`. [Constellation is now compatible with Sitecore 10](https://constellation4sitecore.com/2020/08/11/constellation-is-now-compatible-with-sitecore-10/)

Comment: Seems like this module has a lot of issues, at least for sc 10.2. I spend a lot of time on  discovering this module and now regret about it.  Would not recommend to use it.

Comment: Some issues I have faced and with the help of the module owner I have resolved and I wrote that solution in this blog you can refer, maybe it can help you. https://himmatsinghdulawat.blogspot.com/2021/11/url-redirects-module-in-sitecore.html

Answer (score 1):

There's no Sitecore-specific URL Rewrite to my knowledge, but perhaps IIS URL Rewrite will do?
https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite